# Refactor to avoid global leaks? (underscore js like pattern)

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, refactoring, scope, mocha.js

I'd like to modularize some functions, I'd like to use a pattern like underscore js, but I alwais get a global leak warning.

```js
// simple test use case
var decorate = require('../lib/decorate');
var expect = require('expect.js');

describe('decorate', function() {

  it('should wrap', function() {
    var arr = []
    expect( decorate('dummy').wrapWith(' oOo ') ).to.eql( ' oOo dummy oOo ' );
  });

});
```

Now it pass with `mocha --ignore-leaks` but is possile to wrap it without having the global leak?

This is the basic code:

```js
// decorate.js
(function () {
  // 'use strict'; // not yet

  function Decorate(obj) {
    this._obj = obj; // FIXME: global leaks _obj
    if (!(this instanceof Decorate)){
        return new Decorate(this._obj);
    }
  }

  Decorate.prototype.wrapWith = function(wrap) {
    return wrap + this._obj + wrap;
  }

  // export for node or the browser
  if (typeof module !== 'undefined') {
    module.exports = Decorate;
  } else {
    window.decorate = Decorate;
  }
}.call(this));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
>   function Decorate(obj) {
>     this._obj = obj; // FIXME: global leaks _obj
>     if (!(this instanceof Decorate)){
>         return new Decorate(this._obj);
>     }
>   }
> ```

You have some code in there that allows you to call `Decorate` without `new`, i.e. with `this` not being a `Decorate` instance. If such is detected, a new instance is explicitly created and returned.

However, you are creating the `._obj` property before that test, regardless of the test result! You need to test at the top, and abort the constructor immediately if it is not called as a constructor.

```
  function Decorate(obj) {
    if (!(this instanceof Decorate))
        return new Decorate(obj); // abort! abort!

    this._obj = obj; // Does not leak any more
  }
```